# vue-authenticate and router redirect

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-authenticate

I use **vue-authenticate** (https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate) to login with ID/Password and Oauth 1 & 2.

Where I put the router redirect to redirect user on dashboard page?

```
this.$router.push({name: 'dashboard'})
```

**My code store.js with Vuex:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import {vueAuth} from './auth'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    isAuthenticated: false
  },
  getters: {
    isAuthenticated () {
      return vueAuth.isAuthenticated()
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    isAuthenticated (state, payload) {
      state.isAuthenticated = payload.isAuthenticated
    },
    setProfile (state, payload) {
      state.profile = payload.profile
    }
  },
  actions: {
    login (context, payload) {
      payload = payload || {}
      return vueAuth.login(payload.user, payload.requestOptions).then((response) => {
        context.commit('isAuthenticated', {
          isAuthenticated: vueAuth.isAuthenticated()
        })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .then() after you dispatch your action in your vue component, you can put $router.push() method after your dispatch action completed.

```
// SomeComponent.vue
.
.
.
methods: {
  login () {
    this.$store.dispatch('login', payload)
      .then(() => {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard' })
      })
  }
}
```

Or you can use in your actions.js file but I'm doing $router jobs in vue

```
// actions.js
import Vue from 'vue'

const actions = {
  login (context, payload) {
    payload = payload || {}
    return vueAuth.login(payload.user, payload.requestOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        context.commit('isAuthenticated', {
        isAuthenticated: vueAuth.isAuthenticated()
        Vue.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard' })
      })
    })
  }
}
```